# How to handle configuration change for fragment with view model

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, viewmodel

I want to make my fragment wont re-load the data when configuration change with view model.

So, i try to make an App about gitHub User.
My Main Activity contain Search view to search user and show the result with recyclerview.
My Detail Activity is showing the detail of user when one of user in the list clicked, and in my detail activity i use Tab Layout and view pager to show user's followers and following.

My ViewModel for activity works well and can keep my data when orientation change.
But when i do the same to my fragment, my fragment keep re-loading new data when orientation change.

Here my fragment
i use View Model to request data

```
public class FollowingFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String KEY_FOLLOWING = "key_following";
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private FollowingViewModel followingViewModel;
    private FollowingAdapter followingAdapter;

    ShimmerFrameLayout shimmerFrameLayout;

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    ArrayList<FollowingResponse> followingResponse = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_following, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_following);
        shimmerFrameLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.shimmer_frame_layout2);

        followingViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(FollowingViewModel.class);
        followingAdapter = new FollowingAdapter();
        followingAdapter.setOnItemClickCallback(new FollowingAdapter.OnItemClickCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(FollowingResponse followingResponse) {
                showSelectedItem(followingResponse);
            }
        });

        //this is what i've tried and worked, but my fragment result with double or triple the data.
        if (savedInstanceState == null){

        }
        else {
            followingResponse = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(KEY_FOLLOWING);
        }


        showRecyclerView();
        getData();
    }

    private void getData() {
        followingViewModel.setDataFollowing(DetailUserActivity.clickedUser);
        followingViewModel.getDataFollowing().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<ArrayList<FollowingResponse>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ArrayList<FollowingResponse> followingResponses) {
                shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                shimmerFrameLayout.stopShimmer();
                followingAdapter.setData(followingResponse);
                followingResponse.addAll(followingResponses);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(followingAdapter);
                followingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
    private void showRecyclerView() {
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        followingViewModel.setDataFollowing(DetailUserActivity.clickedUser);
    }

    private void showSelectedItem(FollowingResponse item) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), DetailUserActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("EXTRA_DATA", item.getLogin());
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

        @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        outState.putParcelableArrayList(KEY_FOLLOWING, followingResponse);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

Detail Activity

```
public class DetailUserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView tvName, tvNickname, tvLocation, tvCompany, tvEmail, tvWebsite;
    private TextView tvCountFollowers, tvCountRepository, tvCountFollowing;
    private ImageView imgProfile;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    public static String clickedUser;
    UserViewModel userViewModel;

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    private final String EXTRA_DATA = "EXTRA_DATA";
    private static final String EXTRA_FOLLOW = "extra_follow";

//    Fragment followingFragment;
//    FragmentTransaction transaction;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detail_user_activity);

//        i've tried this, but when the orientation change, my detail activity force close and throw me to my main activity.
//        if (savedInstanceState != null){
//            followingFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, KEY_FOLLOWING);
//        } else {
//            followingFragment = new FollowingFragment();
//
//            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.tv_view_pager, followingFragment).commit();
//        }

        tvName = findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name);
        tvNickname = findViewById(R.id.tv_item_nickname);
        tvLocation = findViewById(R.id.tv_item_location);
        tvCompany = findViewById(R.id.tv_item_company);
        tvEmail = findViewById(R.id.tv_item_email);
        tvWebsite = findViewById(R.id.tv_item_website);
        imgProfile = findViewById(R.id.img_item_photo);
        tvCountFollowers = findViewById(R.id.tv_count_follower);
        tvCountRepository = findViewById(R.id.tv_count_repo);
        tvCountFollowing = findViewById(R.id.tv_count_following);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar2);

        setForUserData();
        setForTabLayout();
        
    }

    private void setForUserData(){
        Intent detailIntent = getIntent();
        clickedUser = detailIntent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_DATA");
        userViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, new ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory()).get(UserViewModel.class);
        userViewModel.setUserUVM(clickedUser);
        userViewModel.getUserUVM().observe(this, new Observer<UserResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(UserResponse userResponse) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load(userResponse.getAvatarUrl())
                        .into(imgProfile);
                tvName.setText(userResponse.getLogin());
                tvLocation.setText(userResponse.getLocation());
                tvNickname.setText(userResponse.getName());
                tvCompany.setText(userResponse.getCompany());
                tvEmail.setText(userResponse.getEmail());
                tvWebsite.setText(userResponse.getBlog());

                tvCountRepository.setText(String.valueOf(userResponse.getPublicRepos()));
                tvCountFollowers.setText(String.valueOf(userResponse.getFollowers()));
                tvCountFollowing.setText(String.valueOf(userResponse.getFollowing()));
            }
        });
    }

    
    private void setForTabLayout(){
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tv_tab_layout);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.tv_view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount()));
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);


        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
        });
    }

    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        int totalTab;
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, int totalTabs) {
            super(fragmentManager);
            this.totalTab = totalTabs;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return new FollowersFragment();
                case 1:
                    return new FollowingFragment();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return totalTab;
        }
    }


//    @Override
//    protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
//       getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, KEY_FOLLOWING, followingFragment );
//       super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
//    }
}
```

im trying to solve my FollowingFragment first, then ill do the same on my FollowerFragment.
im really new in programming, and have no one to ask.. can someone help me to solve my problem with keep data in fragment when orientation change?

Comment: ```followingViewModel.setDataFollowing(DetailUserActivity.clickedUser);``` where is the data for clickedUser coming is this a static varaible in activity?

Comment: yes it is static variable.. `public static String clickedUser;` in detail activity

Answer (score 0):

```
followingViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(FollowingViewModel.class);
```

In Fragment insted of writing this code in onViewCreated() write it inside OnCreate()

onViewCreated() will get called everytime the orientation changes so it will create new instance of view model everytime the orientation changes making viewmodel to reload the data

Comment: I did, but its still doubling my data in my fragment..

Answer (score 0):

If you need to load data only once for the `FollowingViewModel` a good place to do it should be inside the constructor of the view model in this way you won't need to worry about the orientation change of the fragment.

Comment: Sorry i dont really get it. I think i need to load more than once, so in my Detail Activity, on FollowingFragment theres a tablayout that showing list of user, and when one of on the list clicked, it will move to detail of current user clicked.. so i need to request current user clicked information. was my understanding right about load data in `FollowingViewModel`?

Answer (score 0):

when you create the instance of ViewModel in your fragment like this

> followingViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(FollowingViewModel.class);

You are passing `this` as the owner, where this is the fragment itself.
For getting the same instance of View Model, you need to pass the same instance of the owner.

whenever an orientation change happens, The fragment is destroyed and recreated. on re-creation `this` is a different instance, and hence the ViewModel returned by the provider is also different.

what you can do is, use the parent activity of the fragment as the owner.

`followingViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity).get(FollowingViewModel.class);`

since activities are not destroyed in most cases, you will receive the same instance of `FollowingViewModel`.

In cases where the activity is destroyed, the new Activity is capable of retrieving the same old `ViewModelStore` using `NonConfigurationInstances`. Thus Fetching the same view models on recreation. This is the reason why the `UserViewModel` logic was working correctly inside the activity.

follow this link for more details [proandroiddev](https://proandroiddev.com/how-viewmodel-works-under-the-hood-52a4f1ff64cf)